# inheriting the user.home property within my custom .properties file

Tags: java, properties, system-properties

Can I do something like `working-dir="file:${user.home}/some-directory"` within my .properties file? I am using ResourceBundle to load configuration from a .properties file and I would to inherit a system property key such as `user.home` for my `working-dir` property. It would be nice to be able to do this since I can have different versions of the .properties in resource directory of the source package and test package respectively. I want to define different values for `working-dir` for my production and testing environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that directly, however you can parse your properties in your code and programatically expand the variables, e.g.

- Search for the pattern `${varname}` in your property
- Get the value of `varname` from the system properties
- Replace `${varname}` with the value of system property `varname`

Here is a simple implementation of the above:

```
String property = "file:${user.home}/some-directory";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.+)\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(property);
while (matcher.find())
{
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String val = System.getProperty(key);
    if (val != null)
    {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(val));
    }
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried [Apache commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/)'s [variable interpolation](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_basicfeatures.html#Variable_Interpolation) and it works perfect.